# Wildcard matching in Python like powershell

Tags: python-3.x, powershell

I'm trying to convert my PowerShell script into python and I'm still learning python.

```
$Check_env = "ProjectNameStaging"
if ($Check_env -like "*Staging") {
    $Environment = "Staging"
}
elseif ($Check_env -like "*Production") {
    $Environment = "Production"
}
```

I tried to use fnmatch.filter but looks like too much of work in that.

I know it could be done very easily but trying to find the best and less line of code in python for PowerShell scripts because I'm still figuring out to find out how much Python can be used in place of PowerShell.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Consider using glob, either directly ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html ) or via pathlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`fnmatch.fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch) for wildcard matching. Its usage is `fnmatch.fnmatch(string, pattern)`, and will return true if `string` matches with `pattern`. The translated code will be

```
import fnmatch

check_name = "ProjectNameStaging"
if fnmatch.fnmatch(check_name, "*Staging"):
    environment = "Staging"
elif fnmatch.fnmatch(check_name, "*Production"):
    environment = "Production"
```

In this case you can also use [`endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) if you're ok with a solution without wildcard matching. As the name suggests, this will only check if the string ends with a particular suffix.

```
check_name = "ProjectNameStaging"
if check_name.endswith("Staging"):
    environment = "Staging"
elif check_name.endswith("Production"):
    environment = "Production"
```

Comment: cool, it will solve my problem. Thanks for quick answer. Looks like I really need to take a deeper dive to convert my bigger PowerShell scripts into Python scripts.

Comment: @Imran Good to hear :). Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem.